# How to make Hadoop MR to read only files instead of folders in input path

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, recordreader

As per our requirement, the output of one job will be the input of other job.

By using Multiple outputs concepts we are creating a new folder in output path and writing those records into folder. This is how it looks like :

```
OPFolder1/MultipleOP/SplRecords-m-0000*
OPFolder1/part-m-0000* files
```

When the new job is using the input as OPFolder1, I am facing the below error

```
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.open(DistributedFileSystem.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.LineRecordReader.initialize(LineRecordReader.java:85)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:786)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): Path is not a file: /user/abhime01/OPFolder1/MultiplOP/
```

Is there any way or property, to make hadoop, read only the files rather than folders.

Comment: Did you try `OPFolder1/part-m-0000` instead of `OPFolder1` ?

Comment: @YoungHobbit: But I have many part-m-0000* files? You mean to pass the input something like this **OPFolder1/part-m***

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typo earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Set `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` to `true`. See [FileInputFormat doesn't read files recursively in the input path dir](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-3193).

Comment: I dont want to read the subfolders, I just need the files in that main folder to be read.

Comment: Don't mix output with folders. Write the output somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to create custom input format by subclassing default InputFormat class, so that it will allow you to override the listStatus method. While implement the liststatus method you just need to ignore directories inside your input dir.

Example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
FileStatus file = files[i];
if (!file.isDir()) {
newFiles.add(file);
```

Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the root directory for the InputPath, you could use the path:
`OPFolder1/part-m*`, 
which is basically all the files in this directory, whose names start with `part-m`.